# A variation of topologist's sine curve

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A = \{(x,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) | x\in (0,1)\}\cup\{0\}\times [0,1]$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Is $A$ path-connected?

I'm not sure if I understand what $A$ looks like.

I understand that why the original topologist's sine curve is *not* path connected. If I understand correctly, it is similar to why deleted infinite broom is not path connected. Namely, in topologist's sine curve, we cannot find a path from the point $(0,0)$ to the rest part of the graph.

In this example though, I don't understand what the graph looks like, especially the "$\times [0,1]$" part. Is it like topologist's sine curve with $x-$axis $[0,1]$? In this case I suppose $A$ would be path-connected, but the solution says it is not.

Comment: $\{0\} \times [0,1]$ can presumably be re-expressed as $\{(0,y) | y \in [0,1]\}$.  So it's the normal topologist's sine curve plus a piece of the $y$-axis.

Comment: A quick proof of not-path connectedness is [here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_12/sine%20curve.pdf). That it is connected follows from the topologist's sine curve being connected.